# Line of code statistics with out comments

Tags: xcode, shell, lines-of-code

I am trying to get line of code statistics for my xcode code. For that i executed the following command in Terminal to get all possible kinds of codes.

```
find . "(" -name "*.m" -or -name "*.mm" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h" -or -name "*.xml" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | sort
```

It gives me the number of code lines including comments also. Can anyone tell me how to get  line of code statistics without comments.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net), which would give you a nice output like:

```
7892 text files.
4289 unique files.                                          
9574 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.56  T=58.0 s (43.9 files/s, 7442.5 lines/s)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Objective C                     872          44323          20568         198133
HTML                             34           1032              8          76432
C/C++ Header                    908          16427          35415          19872
D                               684              0              0           8299
C                                 8            889            534           4040
MUMPS                             3            618              0           2781
Bourne Shell                     18            175            327            622
Ruby                              2             87             15            380
XML                              10              0              0            264
CSS                               1             41              8            219
Python                            1              9             16             41
Objective C++                     2             15             12             26
Bourne Again Shell                1              4              4             10
YAML                              1              0              0              9
make                              1              2              0              7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           2546          63622          56907         311135
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just copy the file into a folder that's on your PATH (so to somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/cloc`). Then `cd` to your project and run it as `cloc .`. All dependencies should be installed by default on your machine.